# Работа с массивами в PHP. Вычисление и удаление дубликатов

Tags: php, pdo, php7

Всем привет, не могу решить задачу уже 3 день. Помогите пожалуйста. Мне нужно заменить дубликаты значений массива одним, и посчитать сумму элементов с теми же ключами, которые удалили. То есть, есть два массива $arr1, $arr2, мы заменяем в $arr1 одинаковые ключи одним, в данном случае "september", параллельно в $arr2 мы вычисляем сумму с теми же ключами, которые заменяли в $arr1, то есть (2+3+4+5). Спасибо заранее

```
$arr1 = [
1 => "april",
2 => "september",
3 => "september",
4 => "september",
5 => "september",
6 => "may"
];
$arr2 = [
1 => 100,
2 => 5000,
3 => 3200,
4 => 1100,
5 => 2700,
6 => 100
];
```

То, что я пробовал:

```
function debug($str){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($str);
    echo '</pre>';
}
$config = require 'config.php';
$jsonProjectMoney = [];
$jsonProjectTime = [];

try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$config['host']};dbname={$config['dbname']}", 
        $config['username'], $config['password']);
} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    die($exception->message());
}
$queryProject = $connection->prepare("SELECT `money`, `time` FROM `cabinet_logs` WHERE `server` = '0'");
$queryProject->execute();
while($rowProject = $queryProject->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($rowProject);
    $jsonProjectMoney[] = (int) $money;
    $jsonProjectTime[] = gmdate("F", $time);
    echo date("F", $time);
}
debug($jsonProjectTime);
//1590524165
foreach ($jsonProjectTime as $k => $v) {
}
foreach ($jsonProjectMoney as $key => $value) {
}debug(array_unique($jsonProjectTime));
for($y = 0; $y <= count($jsonProjectTime); $y++){
    if($jsonProjectTime[$k] == $jsonProjectTime[$k]) {
        unset($jsonProjectTime[$k]);
        $newelement = $jsonProjectMoney[$k] + $jsonProjectMoney[--$k];
        unset($jsonProjectMoney[++$k]);
        $jsonProjectMoney[--$k] = $newelement;
    }
}
$new = array_unique($jsonProjectTime);
debug($new);
debug($jsonProjectMoney);
json_encode($jsonProjectMoney);
json_encode($jsonProjectTime);
```

Comment: а почему бы не решить эту задачу прям в запросе? SELECT month(`time`) m, sum(`money`) FROM `cabinet_logs` group by m WHERE `server`=0

Comment: @splash58 SELECT `time`, `sum(money)` FROM `cabinet_logs` group by `time` WHERE server = '0' Неожиданный порядок предложений. (near "group by" at position 48)

Comment: групбай в конец, конечно SELECT month(time) m, sum(money) FROM cabinet_logs  WHERE server=0 group by m

Comment: @splash58, а что это за 'm'

Comment: alias, можете выкинуть  и написать group by month(time)

Comment: @splash58 почему - то он выдает это: https://prnt.sc/s79uu6

Comment: а какой тип у поля time?

Comment: @splash58 СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ, НАТОЛКНУЛИ НА ОТЛИЧНУЮ МЫСЛЬ, Я СДЕЛАЛ TASK!!! <3

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял.
Делаешь цикл совпадений в массиве (array_count_values), если найдено больше 1, заменяешь из параллельного массива. Писать не хочу, но надеюсь помог)